como hago para convertir a bytes una imagen para posteriormente pasarla a base64 (estoy usando ASP y Visual Basic
'ASP' donde esta el apartado de la imagen
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1  col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-0">
                        <asp:Label Font-Size="Small" ID="LBL_sRuta" runat="server" Text="Firma" 
                            CssClass="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-1  col-md-3 col-md-offset-2" Style="text-align: left"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:FileUpload Width="300px" ID="ArchivoEnvio" runat="server" CssClass="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-6 col-md-pull-1  btn btn-default" Style="border: hidden;" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

'visual basic' donde estoy realizando la extracion y convercion
     Sub convertir_base64(ByVal m_sFirmaelc As String)
        ArchivoEnvio = Convert.ToBase64String
    End Sub

